# Allow only one decimal value float while entering itself in JTable column?

Tags: java, swing, floating-point, jtable

I implemented the `JTable` in my GUI. And make it 3rd column editable by Overriding `isCellEditable(int row, int column)` in `MyTableModel`.

Now I'm trying to allow only float value with one decimal location to my editable column. I have tried to implement `CellEditorListener`, control is coming to method only after all input edited. But I want to restrict while typing itself.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: *"But i want to restrict while typing itself."*  It is impractical to specify one decimal point on input given `float` and `double` are stored in binary.  Instead use a formatter to limit the **display** to just one digit.  See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more detail.

Comment: 1. use Double, 2. override getColumnClass, 3. have to decide a) use JFormattedTextField as editor or b) leave that for renderer, 4. all mentioned three point are good explained in Oracle tutorial - how to use tables - part renderer and editor

Comment: @mKorbel  I cannot remember the last time I tried to edit a single character!

Comment: Yes.I did this by table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(textField)); I have set filterdocument to the textField what i'm passing. it was working fine.

Comment: @Suseendran P - not you didn't, please re_read my comment again, there weren't something about, DocumentFilter for plain vanilla JTextField is only simulations of JFormattedTextField, have to waiting, never hands up, maybe someone will answering your question